# How to get original element from event?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I am currently using `addEventListener` on a `select`:

```
<select>
    <option value="Apple">Mac</option>
    <option value="Microsoft">Windows</option>
</select>

document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change",function(ev){
    //do something here...
}, false);
```

But I can't figure out how to get the original element from `event`.

PS: I don't want to do this:

```
<select onchange="func(event,this)">
```

This will only mess up the HTML...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element that caused the event is automatically assigned to `this` in the event handler.  It's also in the event data structure which is passed to the `addEventListener()` callback and in your example is `ev.target`.

```
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change",function(ev){
    //do something here...
    // you can use the value of this to access the object that 
    //    is responding to the event
    // you can also look in the event data structure for 
    //    other items like ev.target
}, false);
```

You can see all the members of the event object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event).

Comment: There's a difference between this and ev.target. 'this' is the topmost element which had the event attached, ev.target is the innermost element that received the event.

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk - Yes, if the event  bubbles, `ev.target` and `this` will vary.  At the source of the event, they are the same.